# I am trying to create two separate columns from one column. I have cost type column that has actual and forecast as types

Tags: excel, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

[image]

as shown in the image above, I am trying to separate actuals and forecast as columns. Is there a way to transform a table as shown in the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its filtering and combining.

Use drop down atop the column to filter cost_types  for "actuals". Remove cost_types column. Rename the amount column as actuals

Use drop down atop the column to filter cost_types  for "forecast". Remove cost_types column. Rename the amount column as forecast

combine the two data sets

[image]

sample code:

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],

#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([cost type] = "actual")),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"cost type"}),
#"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"amount", "actuals"}}),

#"Filtered Rows2" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([cost type] = "forecast")),
#"Removed Columns2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows2",{"cost type"}),
#"Renamed Columns2" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns2",{{"amount", "forecast"}}),

combined = Table.Combine({#"Renamed Columns" , #"Renamed Columns2"})
in  combined
```

alternate data structure, which makes more sense to me:

[image]

code:

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"project id", type text}, {"title", type text}, {"manager", type text}, {"dept", type text}, {"Subproject id", type text}, {"effective date", type text}, {"cost type", type text}, {"amount", Int64.Type}}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Changed Type", List.Distinct(#"Changed Type"[#"cost type"]), "cost type", "amount", List.Sum)
in  #"Pivoted Column"
```

Comment: Your suggestion of filtering and combing is very useful. However I also found a simpler way to do it: in power query editor: Select the column > transform > pivot column. Alternative data structure won't work because actuals and forecast will always have different dates. it updates every month.